# how can full clear focus in editText , just like press button DONE on softkeyboard

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I specify different backgrounds when edit text focus changed , but  `clearFocus()`  seem like no effect , because the background do not change to the right state .

Comment: can you please elaborate your question

Comment: Please post what you have tried. Difficult to say anything unless we see the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, we can use `cleareFocus` method to remove the focus.

```
editTextView.clearFocus()
```

But when this method is called, as source code comment says:

> When not in touch-mode, the framework will try to give focus to the first focusable View from the top after focus is cleared. Hence, if this
>   View is the first from the top that can take focus, then all callbacks
>   related to clearing focus will be invoked after which the framework will
>   give focus to this view.

so after you call it, the first element will stay get the focus. so we should set the `touch-mode` true in parent layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:layout_width="0px" 
    android:layout_height="0px"/>
<EditText android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Comment: if you think the answer is good, you can also upvote my answer. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create one more EditText(edit_hidden) and set visibility GONE or INVISIBLE

When you want to clear Focus from your EditText(edit_your) then use this Code

```
 edit_your.clearFocus();
 edit_hidden.requestFocus();
```

Using Action Done Event

```
edit_your.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {        
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
               edit_your.clearFocus();
               edit_hidden.requestFocus();
        }
    return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: well , thks frist , i tried ur way , but the focus still gain by the visible one

Comment: it seem like only visible widget can obtain focus